# shopify get products with same title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, liquid

I need to get the products which are having the same title, by using a title as condition.

I'll get the title condition from `product.title` in `products.liquid`.
is there any way to get it?

Comment: Product.where.(["title ILIKE ? " , "%#{search}%"]) do you need something like this?

Comment: yes.. but i want inside the code.. not from a form. @chaitanya

Comment: Are you looking for the API call "GET" command?